Render in DaVinci Resolve using ffmpeg
I want to cut some clips from main video and export it without re-encoding,  just copying stream, in DaVinci Resolve, but use ffmpeg, is it possible?
I have main video (e.g. a 60 seconds long video), I cut some moment using DaVinci Resolve and get a new video of 40 seconds (I didn't add new text or images inside the video, just cut).
I want to export the new 40 seconds video without decoding like it was using with ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i 60sec.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy 40sec.mp4

For example, I can use this in the software named xvid4psp. I should just choose "Copystream".
Question: Can I use ffmpeg inside the DaVinci Resolve to copystream after cutting the material?

The short and long answers are no.

Streamcopy is not possible, but you can use voukoder to encode using ffmpeg inside Resolve.

about voukoder good idea. i will try

DaVinci Resolve does not have a method for "exporting" a command to an external application or using an external application to perform an action on media you are working on inside it.
You will need to choose one or the other tool, based on your needs, and use it.

But Davinci can use scripts lua, python and api functional
https://resolvedevdoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API_basic.html
Maybe we can use this functions to export from timeline using ffmpeg

Consider using gpac's MP4Box command to avoid re-encoding.
MP4Box -splitz 5:45 "infile.mp4 -out "outfile.mp4", where it starts 5 seconds in and stops at approximately the 45 seconds. (rounds up to next boundry if needed)
use MP4Box -h split for split options help.
I use my custom bash script to split (cut) video files:
https://gist.github.com/nerdCopter/808857ebfe867a61606e03cd8af62f8d
